# Is there a clan war bonus after leaving/being kicked?

Tags: clash-of-clans

A new player joined my clan for the first war. He then attacked number 1, as the enemy base was very easy to get a star, with the particular setup he had.

After he attacked, he left the clan, worried that he would be kicked by our leader.

If we win the war, will he still get a war loot bonus? Would he have received the war loot bonus if he was kicked, instead of voluntarily leaving?

Comment: @ModDL, I see you made a small fix to the question, GJ, but there is still a lot more that has to be done. Please keep in mind that while we appreciate edits, it is much better to perform all the required edits in one go, to prevent unnecessary bumping.

Answer (score 3):

I'll quote from the [wikia](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars):

> **Even if you have left the clan before the war ended, you can still receive the War Bonus if you had successfully attacked at least one base in the Clan War.** Any spectators, however, will not receive any War Bonus whatsoever.

And here *left* includes being kicked.

Comment: Based on other answers here - _kicked_ seems not to be included in this rule.

Comment: @WaldoAwesome Good point. Will have to test it then.

Answer (score 2):

I was kicked out of my clan during the war and I should have gotten over 800k gold and slider but didn't get any.

So from personal experience I can tell you: **no, you won't get any gold**!

Answer (score 1):

I've just get kicked after successfully attacked the opponents. I should get more than 900k bonus. but nothing is in my tressaury to collect and war is now ended. so no!

Answer (score 0):

I just left a clan where I had attacked in war, and after the war ended, I did get the war bonus into my clan castle, even when I was in a different clan at the time of war ending.

I don't know if it is different if you're being kicked. It might be the same here as with the clan games: If you are being kicked before the games end, you don't get any rewards.

Answer (score -1):

You never get any clan war bonus in your treasury if you leave the clan before the end of the clan war.
Bot you you do get it if you join the clan again before the clan war ends.